# Can I use .jar file in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, cross-platform

I have some  web service stored in a `.jar` file. I need to integrate the `.jar` file in my iOS application. Is it possible?

If yes, can anyone help me out with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Java to Objective-C converter have you used and what problems did you encounter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185334/which-java-to-objective-c-converter-have-you-used-and-what-problems-did-you-enco)

Comment: can you run that logic on a server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to integrate the .jar file in my iOS application. Is it possible?

No.

There's no JRE officially available for iOS, so you can not use your Java code directly.

You may want to look for multi-platform developer solutions like Xamarin if you want to re-use your existing logic, but I personally don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about `.jar` file as archive that contains some data (XML files): Yes it is possible to extract them. But running some business logic that is written in Java certainly not because of missing of JRE.

Comment: yes jar file contains xml file. can you provide some reference link to achieve this

Comment: You should work with .jar  files like with archives in swift language